# Changing Load Location of Outlook plugins

Tags: outlook, windows-installer, vsto, outlook-addin, program-files

We have created a **VSTO Plugin** for Outlook. Is it possible to make Outlook look a directory outside of `C:\Program Files` for the location of plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook can look at any directory you choose (*local path, UNC, or HTTP*) - which you [define in your **Manifest** registry key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106.aspx#sectionToggle3). The issue you will have is that installing outside of the `Program Files` directory will require you to have a [**Trusted Publisher Certificate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx) or an [**Inclusion List**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608607.aspx) - another hoop to jump through.

The reasoning is that you [need administrative permissions to install to `Program Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb157863.aspx#GrantingTrustWindowsInstaller), so [Outlook automatically trusts any plugins with their **manifest** pointing to the `Program Files` path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsto/archive/2010/03/08/deploying-your-vsto-add-ins-to-all-users-saurabh-bhatia.aspx).

Comment: Outlook automatically trusts any local add-in, it does not have to be in Program Files.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko For MSI - I think this depends on whether you are installing it for **All Users** or the **Current User**. For **All User** installations, I've had issues getting plugins to work properly if the plugin wasn't loaded from the `Program Files` path.

Comment: Nope, that might make some difference to the .Net run-time, but Outlook itself would not care less: it reads the class name from registry and creates an instance of the COM object that has to implement the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Nothing else matters.